Help identifying a board-to-wire power connector
Trying to identify the part number for this connector, the connector has the marking AMP 2 on its housing, from this i would assume it is made by Amphenol !
The pin pitch is 4.2mm, and its from a Closomat Bidet PCB.




It's a custom derivative of a Molex Mini Fit JR connector or a TE VAL-U-LOK connector.
The standard Molex connector . Note that the polarization inside each cavity looks different.
The standard TE connector . Again, note that the polarization inside each cavity looks different.

AMP 2 on its housing, from this i would assume it is made by Amphenol

No. AMP and Amphenol are different companies. AMP is now owned by TE connectivity.

I did wonder if this was custom made connector as i couldn't find that polarization in all the similar connectors. Looks like i will also need to change the connector plug to match the standard Molex, thanks for your help.

I think you can also carefully shave the plastic down with a knife.
